# Unable to deploy angular2 app with angular-seed in Tomcat server

Tags: angular, tomcat, angular-seed

I want my angular 2 app with angular-seed to be run in tomcat server with predefined folder.
I pulled the code from https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/
I am able to run it in my local i.e. **http://localhost:5555/**.
I build this with npm run build.prod, it generated dist folder with **prod**. I added all this content to **Root** folder of **tomcat server**, I made server to start. Its running in **http://localhost:8080/**
I want it should run like **http://localhost:8080/myapp/**
I have tried by adding **myapp** folder  in **webapps** folder of tomcat, and copied the content of **prod** folder of dist. 
I am getting the error like [image]
Can any of you help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base argument is required.

```
npm run build.prod -- --base=/myapp/
```